# How to animate a widget by non-linear path?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a floating widget which I want to animate moving across the screen on a Bezier path.
I already have a path var which changes according to drag and fling gestures (predefined final offset).
How do I make the widget follow such a path?

Edit: as per request here's the code.
It's mostly a fork of https://pub.dev/packages/pip_view package.
You can look at the _onPadEnd, which is where I'm triggering the animation. Just trying to see how to make it follow a Bezier path.

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dismiss_keyboard.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:math' hide log;
import 'package:arc_animator/arc_animator.dart'; //unused import

double sqrtNegSup(double val){ return val.isNegative ? -(sqrt(-val)) : sqrt(val); }
Map<PIPViewCorner, Offset> _calculateOffsets({Size spaceSize, Size widgetSize, EdgeInsets windowPadding,}) {
  Offset getOffsetForCorner(PIPViewCorner corner) {
    final spacing = 16;
    final left = spacing + windowPadding.left;
    final top = spacing + windowPadding.top;
    final right = spaceSize.width - widgetSize.width - windowPadding.right - spacing;
    final bottom = spaceSize.height - widgetSize.height - windowPadding.bottom - spacing;

    switch (corner) {
      case PIPViewCorner.topLeft: return Offset(left, top);
      case PIPViewCorner.topRight: return Offset(right, top);
      case PIPViewCorner.bottomLeft: return Offset(left, bottom);
      case PIPViewCorner.bottomRight: return Offset(right, bottom);
      default: throw Exception('Not implemented.');
    }
  }

  final corners = PIPViewCorner.values;
  final Map<PIPViewCorner, Offset> offsets = {};
  for (final corner in corners) {
    offsets[corner] = getOffsetForCorner(corner);
  }

  return offsets;
}
enum PIPViewCorner {
  topLeft,
  topRight,
  bottomLeft,
  bottomRight,
}
class _CornerDistance {
  final PIPViewCorner corner;
  final double distance;
  _CornerDistance({this.corner, this.distance,});
}
class PIPView extends StatefulWidget {
  final PIPViewCorner initialCorner;
  final double floatingWidth;
  final double floatingHeight;
  final bool avoidKeyboard;

  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, bool isFloating, ) builder;
  const PIPView({
    Key key, @required this.builder,
    this.initialCorner = PIPViewCorner.topRight,
    this.floatingWidth,
    this.floatingHeight,
    this.avoidKeyboard = true,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override PIPViewState createState() => PIPViewState();
  static PIPViewState of(BuildContext context) {return context.findAncestorStateOfType<PIPViewState>();}
}





/// pan functions correspond to callbacks of dragging gestures
/// those functions will update the last drag and offset vars accordingly
///
/// animations are performed independently
/// and are triggered when toggling or dragging is concluded
class PIPViewState extends State<PIPView> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Widget _bottomView;

  AnimationController _toggleFloatingAnimationController; //animation for toggling PIP
  AnimationController _dragAnimationController; //animation for dragging PIP

  PIPViewCorner _corner;
  Offset _dragOffset = Offset.zero;
  bool _isDragging = false;
  Map<PIPViewCorner, Offset> _offsets = {};

  //screenspace
  double width;
  double height;


  //values for refining fling engagement (see usages)
  double baseAdditionOfFlingVelocity = 0.75;
  double baseMultiplierOfFlingVelocity = 2;

  //values for refining fling duration (see usages)
  int minimumDuration = 730;
  int maximumDuration = 1280;
  double durationMultiplier = 1.10;


  bool _isAnimating() { return _toggleFloatingAnimationController.isAnimating || _dragAnimationController.isAnimating; }
  @override void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _corner = widget.initialCorner;
    _toggleFloatingAnimationController = AnimationController(duration: defaultAnimationDuration, vsync: this,);
    _dragAnimationController = AnimationController(duration: defaultAnimationDuration, vsync: this,);
  }
  void _updateCornersOffsets({ Size spaceSize, Size widgetSize, EdgeInsets windowPadding,}) {_offsets = _calculateOffsets(spaceSize: spaceSize, widgetSize: widgetSize, windowPadding: windowPadding,);}
  _CornerDistance _calculateNearestCornerAndDistance({Offset offset, Map<PIPViewCorner, Offset> offsets,}) {
    _CornerDistance calculateDistance(PIPViewCorner corner) {
      final distance = offsets[corner].translate(-offset.dx, -offset.dy,).distanceSquared;
      return _CornerDistance(corner: corner, distance: distance,);
    }
    final distances = PIPViewCorner.values.map(calculateDistance).toList();
    distances.sort((cd0, cd1) => cd0.distance.compareTo(cd1.distance));

    return _CornerDistance(corner:distances.first.corner,distance:distances.first.distance);
  }
  _CornerDistance _calculateNearestCornerAndDistanceWithFling({Offset offsetWithFling, Offset offsetWithoutFling, Map<PIPViewCorner, Offset> offsets,}) {
    _CornerDistance calculateDistance(PIPViewCorner corner) {
      final distance = offsets[corner].translate(-offsetWithFling.dx, -offsetWithFling.dy,).distanceSquared;
      return _CornerDistance(corner: corner, distance: distance,);
    }
    final distances = PIPViewCorner.values.map(calculateDistance).toList();
    distances.sort((cd0, cd1) => cd0.distance.compareTo(cd1.distance));

    final actualDistance = offsets[distances.first.corner].translate(-offsetWithoutFling.dx, -offsetWithoutFling.dy).distanceSquared;
    return _CornerDistance(corner:distances.first.corner, distance: actualDistance);
  }
  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    var windowPadding = mediaQuery.padding;
    if (widget.avoidKeyboard) {windowPadding += mediaQuery.viewInsets;}
    final isFloating = _bottomView != null;



    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        width = constraints.maxWidth;
        height = constraints.maxHeight;
        double floatingWidth = widget.floatingWidth;
        double floatingHeight = widget.floatingHeight;
        if (floatingWidth == null && floatingHeight != null) {floatingWidth = width / height * floatingHeight;}
        floatingWidth ??= 100.0;
        if (floatingHeight == null) {floatingHeight = height / width * floatingWidth;}

        final floatingWidgetSize = Size(floatingWidth, floatingHeight);
        final fullWidgetSize = Size(width, height);

        _updateCornersOffsets(spaceSize: fullWidgetSize, widgetSize: floatingWidgetSize, windowPadding: windowPadding,);

        final calculatedOffset = _offsets[_corner];

        // BoxFit.cover
        final widthRatio = floatingWidth / width;
        final heightRatio = floatingHeight / height;
        final scaledDownScale = widthRatio > heightRatio
            ? floatingWidgetSize.width / fullWidgetSize.width
            : floatingWidgetSize.height / fullWidgetSize.height;

        return Stack( children: <Widget>[
            if (isFloating) Navigator(onGenerateRoute: (settings) {return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {return _bottomView;});},),

            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: Listenable.merge([_toggleFloatingAnimationController, _dragAnimationController,]),
              builder: (context, child) {
                final animationCurve = CurveTween(curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,);
                // final animationArc =
                //region assign corresponding keys of controller and animation
                final dragAnimationValue= animationCurve.transform(_dragAnimationController.value,);
                final toggleFloatingAnimationValue = animationCurve.transform(_toggleFloatingAnimationController.value,);
                //endregion

                final floatingOffset = _isDragging ? _dragOffset : Tween<Offset>(begin: _dragOffset, end: calculatedOffset,)
                    .transform(_dragAnimationController.isAnimating ? dragAnimationValue : toggleFloatingAnimationValue);
                final borderRadius = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 10,).transform(toggleFloatingAnimationValue);
                final width = Tween<double>(begin: fullWidgetSize.width, end: floatingWidgetSize.width,).transform(toggleFloatingAnimationValue);
                final height = Tween<double>(begin: fullWidgetSize.height, end: floatingWidgetSize.height,).transform(toggleFloatingAnimationValue);
                final scale = Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: scaledDownScale,).transform(toggleFloatingAnimationValue);
                return Positioned(
                  left: floatingOffset.dx,
                  top: floatingOffset.dy,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onPanStart: isFloating ? _onPanStart : null,
                    onPanUpdate: isFloating ? _onPanUpdate : null,
                    onPanCancel: isFloating ? _onPanCancel : null,
                    onPanEnd: isFloating ? _onPanEnd : null, //pass floatingWidgetSize
                    onTap: isFloating ? stopFloating : null,
                    child: Material(
                      elevation: 10,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
                      child: Container(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
                        ),
                        width: width,
                        height: height,
                        child: Transform.scale(
                          scale: scale,
                          child: OverflowBox(
                            maxHeight: fullWidgetSize.height,
                            maxWidth: fullWidgetSize.width,
                            child: IgnorePointer(
                              ignoring: isFloating,
                              child: child,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Builder(builder: (context) => widget.builder(context, isFloating),),
            ),
          ],);
      },
    );
  }
  //region padEndLogs
    void logFlingDetails(DragEndDetails details){
      // details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.translate(translateX, translateY)
      log(
          "fling details"
              +"\n dx sqrt: " + sqrtNegSup(details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx).toInt().toString()
              +"\n dy sqrt: " + sqrtNegSup(details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy).toInt().toString()
              +"\n direction: " + details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.direction.toString()
      );
    }
    void logOffsetDetails(Offset _off, bool beforeApplyingFling){
      log(
          (beforeApplyingFling ? "offset details BEFORE applying fling params" : "offset details AFTER applying fling params")
              +"\n dx: " + _off.dx.toInt().toString()
              +"\n dy: " + _off.dy.toInt().toString()
              +"\n direction: " + _off.direction.toString()
      );
    }
    void logCornerCalculationDetails(_CornerDistance cornerDistanceDetails, bool withFling){
      log(
          (withFling?"cornerDistanceDetails AFTER fling":"cornerDistanceDetails BEFORE fling")
              +"\n nearest corner: " + cornerDistanceDetails.corner.toString()
              +"\n distance: " + cornerDistanceDetails.distance.toInt().toString()
      );

    }
    //endregion

  //region toggles & gestures
  /*toggle pip on, arg is page over which it will be presented*/ void presentBelow(Widget widget) {
    if (_isAnimating() || _bottomView != null) return;
    dismissKeyboard(context);
    setState(() {_bottomView = widget;});
    _toggleFloatingAnimationController.forward();
  }
  /*toggle pip off, triggered on tap*/ void stopFloating() {
    if (_isAnimating() || _bottomView == null) return;
    dismissKeyboard(context);
    _toggleFloatingAnimationController.reverse().whenCompleteOrCancel(() {if (mounted) {setState(() {_bottomView = null;});}});
  }

  void _onPanCancel() {
    if (!_isDragging) return;
    setState(() {
      _dragAnimationController.value = 0;
      _dragOffset = Offset.zero;
      _isDragging = false;
    });
  }
  void _onPanStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    if (_isAnimating()) return;
    setState(() {_dragOffset = _offsets[_corner]; _isDragging = true;});
  }
  void _onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    if (!_isDragging) return;
    setState(() {_dragOffset = _dragOffset.translate(details.delta.dx, details.delta.dy,);});
  }
  void _onPanEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    if (!_isDragging) return;

    //region fling values
    double minimum = min(width, height);
    double flingDx = sqrtNegSup(details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx) * ((width / minimum) + baseAdditionOfFlingVelocity) * baseMultiplierOfFlingVelocity;
    double flingDy = sqrtNegSup(details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy) * ((height / minimum) + baseAdditionOfFlingVelocity) * baseMultiplierOfFlingVelocity;
    //endregion

    Offset offsetWithFling = _dragOffset.translate(flingDx, flingDy);
    final nearestCornerToUse = _calculateNearestCornerAndDistanceWithFling(offsetWithFling: offsetWithFling,offsetWithoutFling: _dragOffset,offsets: _offsets );

    setState(() { _corner = nearestCornerToUse.corner; _isDragging = false; });


    //region duration values
    int newDuration = (sqrt(nearestCornerToUse.distance)*durationMultiplier).toInt();
    if(newDuration<minimumDuration) newDuration=minimumDuration;
    if(newDuration>maximumDuration) newDuration=maximumDuration;
    //endregion
    log("new duration is: "+newDuration.toString());
    _dragAnimationController.duration = Duration(milliseconds: newDuration.toInt());

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(_dragOffset.dx, _dragOffset.dy);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(flingDx, flingDy, _offsets[nearestCornerToUse.corner].dx, _offsets[nearestCornerToUse.corner].dy);

    double jDx = calculate(path, _dragAnimationController).dx;
    double jDy = calculate(path, _dragAnimationController).dy;



    _dragAnimationController.forward().whenCompleteOrCancel(() { _dragAnimationController.value = 0; _dragOffset = Offset.zero; });
  }
  //endregion

  Offset calculate(Path path, value) {
    PathMetrics pathMetrics = path.computeMetrics();
    PathMetric pathMetric = pathMetrics.elementAt(0);
    value = pathMetric.length * value;
    Tangent pos = pathMetric.getTangentForOffset(value);
    return pos.position;
  }
}```


  [1]: https://pub.dev/packages/pip_view
````

Comment: post your existing code then

Comment: @pskink added! I hope it's relevant.